# Changing background color of input boxes in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have the following code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime
from datetime import date

columns = ["TYPE","DIRECTION","DATE","OPTION"]
param = (20,3) # size of the main window

def GUI():
    sg.theme('Dark Brown 1')
    listing = [sg.Text(u, size = param) for u in columns]
    core = [
    sg.Listbox(['In Book', 'New Trade', 'Old Book'],enable_events=False,key='TYPE', background_color='red', size = (20,1)),
    sg.Input(size = param),
    sg.Input(size = param),
    sg.Input(size = param, key='OPTION')]

    mesh = [[x,y] for (x,y) in list(zip(listing, core))]
    layout =[[sg.Button("SEND")]]+ mesh
    window = sg.Window('Trade Entry System', layout, font='Courier 12').Finalize()
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == "SEND":
            break
        elif event == "TYPE":
            if values[event] == 'In Book':
                window["OPTION"].update(background_color='red')
        else:
            print("OVER")
    window.close()
GUI()
```

I am trying to find a way to say that: if the text 'In Book' in the Listbox is selected then the input box next to OPTION should now have a red background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if content of Listbox `TYPE` is `['EQUITY']` in event loop when event is from Listbox `TYPE`, then call method `update` of input `OPTION` with option `background='red'`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime
from datetime import date

columns = ["TYPE","DIRECTION","DATE","OPTION"]
param = (20,3) # size of the main window

def GUI():
    sg.theme('Dark Brown 1')
    listing = [sg.Text(u, size = param) for u in columns]
    core = [
    sg.Listbox(['In Book', 'New Trade', 'Old Book'], enable_events=True, key='TYPE', background_color='red', size = (20,3)),
    sg.Input(size = param),
    sg.Input(size = param),
    sg.Input(size = param, key='OPTION')]

    mesh = [[x,y] for (x,y) in list(zip(listing, core))]
    layout =[[sg.Button("SEND")]]+ mesh
    window = sg.Window('Trade Entry System', layout, font='Courier 12').Finalize()
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == "SEND":
            break
        elif event == "TYPE":
            if values[event] == ['In Book']:
                window["OPTION"].update(background_color='red')
            else:
                window["OPTION"].update(background_color=sg.theme_input_background_color())
        else:
            print("OVER")
    window.close()
GUI()
```

Comment: I have made some edits to the question, any help would be great.

Comment: "the input box next to OPTION" ? OPTION is the last one input box ... Update code as above if for the input box OPTION.